# MBCalendarKit showing black screen in basic tabbed application

Tags: swift, viewcontroller, mbcalendarkit

I'm fairly new to swift & Xcode and I'm using a basic "tabbed" application template in XCode and I am trying to implement the MBCalendarKit to show a calendar on the first tab view. I am using Cocoapods for the MBCalendar kit. The Basic tabbed application starts with the following files:

[image: files]

The author of MBCalendarKit explains that :

"You can show an instance of CKCalendarView. Use this if you want to manually manage your view hierarchy or have a finer control over your calendar view." :

```
/*
Here's how you'd show a CKCalendarView from within a view controller. 
It's just four easy steps.
*/

// 0. In either case, import CalendarKit:
#import "CalendarKit/CalendarKit.h"

// 1. Instantiate a CKCalendarView
CKCalendarView *calendar = [CKCalendarView new];

// 2. Optionally, set up the datasource and delegates
[calendar setDelegate:self];
[calendar setDataSource:self];

// 3. Present the calendar 
[[self view] addSubview:calendar];
```

And I also followed some of the example code that was provided although most of it was in objective-c. Currently when running the program, On the first tab view, I'm just getting a black screen. How can I fix this to present the calendar itself? I have also looked at the other CalendarKit posts on stackoverflow but none seem to tackle something as specific as this.

My FirstViewController.swift (Which is basically identical to that provided by the author) :

```
import UIKit
import MBCalendarKit

class FirstViewController: CKCalendarViewController, CKCalendarViewDataSource {

    var data : NSMutableDictionary

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

        data = NSMutableDictionary()

        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {

        self.data = NSMutableDictionary()
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        //  Step 0 : Wire up the data source and delegate
        self.delegate = self
        self.dataSource = self

        //  Step 1 : Define some test events
        let title : NSString = NSLocalizedString("Some random event", comment: "")
        let date : NSDate = NSDate(day: 20, month: 12, year: 2015)
        let event : CKCalendarEvent = CKCalendarEvent(title: title as String, andDate: date, andInfo: nil)

        //  Step 2 : Add the events to the cache array
        self.data[date] = [event]

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    //
    //  MARK: - CKCalendarDataSource
    //

    func calendarView(calendarView: CKCalendarView!, eventsForDate date: NSDate!) -> [AnyObject]! {

        return self.data.objectForKey(date) as! [AnyObject]!
    }

    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

and the AppDelegate.swift:

```
import UIKit
import MBCalendarKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

        var viewController: CKCalendarViewController = FirstViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)

        self.window!.rootViewController = viewController
        self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }


}
```

Also when creating the FirstViewController() in the AppDelegate file I was a little unsure of the nibName and bundle arguments. If someone could please explain this as I tried to look it up on Apples reference documentation but it still wasn't clear, and for all I know the fact that I passe nil for both could be my issue? If anyone has experience with CalendarKit or can help me out that would be great,

Cheers

Comment: It looks like you're missing step 3. I don't see where you add the calendar view to the view hierarchy.